# Force autoplay to fail for audio element on Chrome 71 desktop

Tags: google-chrome, audio, autoplay

I'm adding an audio element to a website and it's supposed to autoplay on page load. In Chrome 71, there were some [updates which should disable autoplay](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/11/web-audio-autoplay) of audio and video in certain cases (if the user has not interacted with the page, or the page is not one the user frequents and allows videos to play on, etc). [chrome://media-engagement/](http://chrome://media-engagement/) shows the chrome user's engagement score for different websites (based on how many times they've visited and watched videos).

Typically, the user will have to log in before seeing the page I've added the element to, so it should autoplay without issue in those cases. I'm trying to figure out how to create a situation in which Chrome will prevent the autoplay, so I can test my method for restarting the audio after its been prevented.

The issue is, I can't seem to get Chrome to prevent autoplay. So far I've tried (all on Mac unless otherwise noted):

- After signing in, navigating directly to the url (in the same window after hard refresh/cache clear and in a new window)
- Visiting it as another chrome user, and as a guest user (both of which have no media-engagement scores for the website)
- setting **chrome://flags#autoplay-policy** to **Document user activation is required.** and testing the above (this seemed to be defunct)
- Testing all of the above on another person's computer, who has never visited the site before
- Testing all of the above on BrowserStack Chrome 71 on Windows

I'm not sure what else to do at this point, does anyone know how best to force Chrome to prevent this audio from autoplaying, or create a situation in which that will happen?

Here's the html of the audio element:

```
<div id="intro_player_wrapper">
  <audio id="intro_player" controls="controls">
    <source id="audio_intro_mp3_src" type="audio/mpeg" src="audio_source.mp3" /></source>
    <source id="audio_intro_wav_src" type="audio/wav" src="audio_source.wav" /></source>
  </audio>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript that starts the autoplay:

```
var autoplay_interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    var promise = $("#intro_player").get(0).play();
    if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(_ => {
            intro_audio_played = true;
            clearInterval(autoplay_interval);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Autoplay was prevented.");
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You can try `$("#intro_player").prop('muted', false);` but I think it'll be ignored and continue playing...You can try inserting the player dynamically as well. There are a couple of major variations as well (`innerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML()`, `appendChild()`, etc.)

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for your suggestions. I don't understand how they will help me though. The <audio> already has muted=false by default. And are you suggesting I insert the player after some user interaction has happened? Or when? In either case, the player as it is should work fine for most situations. Maybe it was unclear what I'm asking. What I'm trying to do is create or simulate a situation in which Chrome will prevent autoplay. This will then allow me to test how I should respond in the event that that does happen, on a user's computer. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understood clearly, the `muted` idea is to set it explicitly because being muted is one of Chrome's many requirements for autoplay. If you recall, I wrote *"but I think it'll be ignored and continue playing..."*.  As for the dynamic element idea, you would add it before the user could interact with it.

Comment: @zer00ne Ok thank you for clarifying :j I'll try those and see if either works

Comment: @zer00ne muted didn't seem to work. I'm trying the dynamic element idea, but I don't understand how this is supposed to help. I'm adding the element on page load using jQuery, but it hasn't caused any change in autoplay behavior. Was this intended to not meet one of the requirements (and break autoplay), or suggested as a method of adding the element that would make autoplay work under chrome's requirements? Thanks for your tips and help.

Comment: The former, it is your intention to trigger the policy to step in and prohibit autoplay, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne yes that is my intention